# How do I redact information when my black marker isn't "wet" enough, and the information shows through my blackouts?

Tags: office-supplies, paper

So, I need to redact some information on my tax returns before sending them into my insurance company as proof of citizenship (or something, I'm not sure what exactly they needed them for). The problem is, I tried blacking them out with a dry erase marker and my SSN and financial info show straight through. I've tried going over them a few times and still nothing. I've run them through a copier, hoping it wouldn't catch the subtle differences in ink tones and would just show a black bar, but you can still see the SSN. How can I fully black out this information?

Comment: You should find out exactly why the insurance is asking for a copy of your tax returns. They are not in any way proof of citizenship. There's a good chance that they want to know things like whether or not you have a job or what your income is. The information you're trying to redact could very well be what they're looking for.

Comment: @RossRidge They give explicit instructions to black out the SSN and any financial information.

Comment: Use white out, then make a copy.

Comment: **"black out the SSN and any financial information"** After your name, date, etc., what's left in a tax information that's not "financial information"?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I was requested to provide a redacted copy of my tax return to prove my marital status.  It is called a dependency audit.  I don't know why it is being requested of the OP.

Comment: @Emory That'd be it; they needed both my and my wife's tax returns. It's the first year that she's covered under this plan (we were married in october), so that probably has something to do with it.

Comment: I do work and do file for tax return in a country where I'm not a citizen, but where I'm residing legally. So a tax return is no way a proof of citizenship. You didn't specify your country, but usually citizenship is proved with an ID card or a passport.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you are able to make copies of the forms, create a *digital* copy instead. Then you can "black out" the information digitally with any photo editor or your favorite PDF software. Replace the target text with a black box or just remove it completely.

Then reprint the redacted copies as needed.

*Bonus that you're not destroying the original.*

Comment: +1 This will work, but don't send the electronic copy with this method- if you don't know what  you are doing the original text can remain in the file even though it's not visible on a printout, so it can easily be recovered by anyone with a text editor.

Comment: If you are going to send the result digitally then you need to make sure you use an image editor not "your favourite PDF software" and make sure you save the result in a flat bitmap format (NOT a vector/metafile format, NOT a fancy multilayer image format)

Comment: @Peter Green why take a chance.  (1) scan and create digital copy 1 (2) redact (3) print out (4) scan and create digital copy 2.  Distribute digital copy 2 not digital copy 1.  Paper is not that expensive.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm curious about your comment. I see how it could be true for layered files (like Photoshop files), but for a PNG (or BMP or JPG), could the original text still be stored in the file? Seems like a waste of digital space for a compressed PNG.

Comment: @BrettFromLA The particular case I'm thinking of, I think they just covered it with a black block in a PDF. The text was still there if you deleted the block with a PDF editor or looked at the file with a text editor. [Here](http://www.planetpdf.com/mainpage.asp?webpageid=808). Not applicable in this case, but Word files are also suspect.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks for the examples. They make sense.  I thought there was some PNG "history" feature that I didn't know about.

Comment: @BrettFromLA There have been cases where the image had an embedded thumbnail, and the image editor didn't update the thumbnail, so the thumbnail showed the unredacted information.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Also if you have an image format such as JPEG that contains large amounts of metadata, you might accidentially transmit confidential metadata.

Comment: @emory You don't even need to print. Take a screenshot after editing, and paste the image into a Word document, and presto! :-)

Comment: @Shokhet it depends how paranoid you are.  I would not 100% trust that redacts the information.  If you want to be ultra sure, print it out and redact with scissors - not black marker.  If you are less paranoid, then your way is fine.

Answer (score 27):

Make a regular copy, then cut out the redacted information on the copy before you send it.

Comment: Given the tools mentioned in the post, copier, black marker, I'd say this is the best, easiest choice.

Comment: An X-Acto knife or box cutter and an old catalog or cutting board to cut against will make this 100% sure. Cut it out of a copy of the original, then copy again.

Comment: @AdamDavis especially if you plan on doing this only one time, it is not worth it to figure out how to erase metadata from a digital file

Answer (score 12):

Put some opaque tape over the sensitive information before making your copy.  You could try masking tape or electrician's tape.  You might not want to use the auto paper feed on your copier because the tape might come off inside the copier.

Answer (score 5):

Take a copy of the document, cut out the sections you want to redact. Put a blank sheet of paper behind it (optionally with black behind the holes, according to how you want the redacted sections to show), copy it again.

Or, of course, a digital equivalent, which is to edit by placing plain blocks over the redacted sections (do not use blur tools), then print out.

You can mess about with ink and whiteout and so on, and you can kind of squint at the result and think about whether or not *you* find it illegible. And you'll probably be right. But if you want to redact something, having in your pocket while the rest of the document is on the copier is the best way to be sure it doesn't somehow show through :-)

Also be careful about the *size* of the sections you remove. For SSN they're all the same, so this tells the attacker nothing. For financial information, knowing the number of digits in a redacted number might be a close enough estimate for whatever purpose they had in mind (and the number of line-items on your tax return is also slightly sensitive). Therefore where possible remove the entire box, not just the part of it you used.

Answer (score 3):

I've found very few markers are up to the task of blacking out printer ink, but worry not, there is another way! When most people think of redaction, they think of blacking out data, but I've found whiteout to be far more effective. Just whiteout the data you don't want to send, and all will be well. If you really want it to be black, first apply a coat of whiteout, then just mark over it with your marker. Like the OP mentioned, it's also not a bad idea to run the redacted version through a photocopier, as even with the original there are a number of ways to get ink to show through, but it's much harder on a photocopied version.

Answer (score 3):

You can obfuscate each character individually with a ballpoint pen. Make sure the ink is the same color as the ink you're obfuscating.  Then draw a shape over the top of each letter; I like using a figure "8" with an "X" through it. That will make every character look like every other character:  an "8" looks like an "E" and like an "F", and also a "9" and an "X" and a "0".

[image]

DISCLAIMER: This isn't a perfect solution (obviously!). With enough time, someone could probably read all the information you tried to hide, especially if they used additional tools like chemicals, heat, high-res scanners, etc. But I've found that it's good enough for those day-to-day situations where you want to make it really hard to read certain text.

Comment: Someone upvoted, then downvoted this. I'd like to hear from the downvoter! :)

Comment: There's no way a ballpoint pen ink will match a printed document's ink.

Comment: I should have been more specific. I just meant that if the printed document is black, use a black ballpoint pen. If the printed document is some other color, use that color ink. The key is that one solid wide black mark won't obscure text as well as thin lines that are similar in width to the letters under them. I have done this for years, and I've never been able to read the original text. You can try it if you want! It works best if the lines you draw overlap the lines that were printed.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree (*I've done the same at times*), but in the specific examples shown I easily see the "1 2 3 4 etc..", I think the patterns are too perfect in typed text for it to be a good example - I actually happened to look at the "After" image first, saw the 1 2 3, and then checked the before image to check if I was seeing things how I thought I was.

Comment: Counter-counterespionage: There's an entire thread about [Removing Ink That's Scribbled on top of Printed Text](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10139/remove-ink-thats-scribbled-on-top-of-printed-text)

Comment: That's not forensically secure.

Comment: Better: write random characters ovef it, preferably several layers. No, it ism't "forensically secure", but it interacts with the way humans read to make the eye have trouble retrieving the info -- the reader gets confused about which lines to follow,

Comment: @keshlam that is the whole danger of the method, the information looks obliterated to the untrained eye but it isn't actaully obliterated.

Comment: Tools for tasks. Depends on what you're trying to guard against. If really concerned, it is hard to beat scissors zapplied to a photocopy.

Comment: This is a horrible idea for the stated purpose—it only is safe for text written with the same pen, not too long ago. Various chemical treatments combined with different wavelengths of light, then high-resolution digital scanning and image filtering to bring out minuscule differences can recover the original text.

Comment: @ErikE The stated purpose is "sending them into my insurance company as proof of citizenship ". I don't think someone at the insurance company is going to use various chemical treatments combined with different wavelengths of light and then use high-resolution digital scanning and image filtering. I understood that the OP just didn't want that information to be obvious to someone looking at the page.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Okay, that's a fair take on the issue, though I think answers should be timeless and address a wide audience. Those besides the OP with a similar (though perhaps not identical question) visiting this page for the rest of stackexchange's life need to be guided properly. If you add information in your answer about its limitations and suitability or lack thereof for guaranteed privacy in every situation, I'll delete my comments. In the meantime, I think my comments round out your answer in a helpful way. Oh, and heat can erase ink, too (try a candle).

Comment: @ErikE Thanks for the thoughtful response! I agree that in the future, some people will read this question and want to COMPLETELY hide text on a page. (I've upvoted a few other answers that do this exceedingly well!) If you want to remove your comments that's fine, but not necessary. They explain why I'm writing this, and why I added the disclaimer! :)

Answer (score 3):

Some copiers might have a mode for a pure black-and-white, non-halftone copy. Computer scanners nearly always have ("lineart mode"). If that is not available, physically cutting out the redacted information is definitely the safest way.

Answer (score 2):

Cut out slips of paper that match the size of the boxes that you want to black out, then tape them in place with clear tape so that nothing is redacted that doesn't need to be.

Most photocopiers I've used won't scan words from behind another paper of standard thickness.

Comment: This seems like a lot of work to cover up a few lines.

Answer (score -1):

The variety of contemplations here are absolutely nuts, but I've (almost) been there.  The simplest solution is a nice broad tip (1/8") felt tip pen (similar to a Paper Mate.  Choose your weapon at an Art Supply store.  Then double redact, scan and send.  The Paper Mate type felt tip markers don't bleed through and the broader tip types you can find at the art supply give you better coverage for line-per-line stroke out of entire account numbers, transfers, store names, etc.  I am redacting the Bankruptcy Court's request for all my bank records and tax returns.  Even the Court trustee's paralegal said it was "a matter of law," that I redact my information before transmitting it even to them... something my own attorney didn't have the acumen to tell me.  Invest in redacting tools like these markers, blackout stamps, and have fun. Think of it as an electronic shredder.

Comment: This pretty much sounds like exactly what OP said *didn't work for him*.

Comment: @sidney  That sounds true but I'm a bit confused.  Aren't you OP?  Or don't I understand how these sites work?